# Identity function on set which isn't domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have a function $f:A\to B$, then (as far as I understand)

$$A\xrightarrow{f\times id_A} B\times A$$

takes an element $a\in A$ to $(f(a),a)$.

But what if we have $g:C\to A$ and we try to form $g\times id_A$. What is it?

Asking because it's what appears in some lecture notes from my uni which are generally remarkably typo-free, although I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

**If** your lecture notes are speaking of the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two functions $f : A \to B$ and $g : X \to Y$, this is a function $f \times g : A \times X \to B \times Y$ with :

> $(f \times g)(a, b) = (f(a), g(b))$.

Thus, if $f : A \to B$ and $g : C \to A$, we habe that :

> $f \times id_A : A \times A \to B \times A$

and :

> $g \times id_A : C \times A \to A \times A$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "type-mismatch" here-the domain of $f \times \text{id}_A$ is not $A$, but rather $A \times A$.  Perhaps what is meant is the *composition*

$(f \times \text{id}_A) \circ \Delta$, where;

$\Delta: A \to A \times A$ is the "diagonal function" that sends $a \mapsto (a,a)$?

$g$ appears to be more of a problem, the domain of $g \times \text{id}_A$ is $C \times A$ and there is no "canonical" function $C \to C \times A$ unless $A$ has a distinguished point.